# How to scroll characters on a label in Cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite on which there is a label (CCLabelTTF). On that label i have A,B,C,D,E, etc printed when they are clicked. I want them to **scroll left**. I've googled some tuorials but i am unable to find the solution and stuck here for long. [Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69616692@N06/6328857450/in/photostream/) is the screenshot of my game. You can see the characters from A to J. When i click on more incoming characters, that portion should scroll. What can i do to make the characters scroll?

Here is the code from which the characters are shown on label (lblSelectedAlpha) added on sprite:-

```
-(void)showSelectedAlphaBet{

    fSelectedAlphaY =26;     
    if (tempBackground) {       
        [tempBackground removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }   
    tempBackground = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"stripe_2.png"];
    tempBackground.position = ccp(160,30);
    [self addChild:tempBackground z:30];        
    for (int i=0; i<[arryAddSelectedChar count]; i++) {     
       // NSLog(@"[arryAddSelectedChar count] %@",[arryAddSelectedChar objectAtIndex:i]);       
        lblSelectedAlpha = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:
                        [arryAddSelectedChar objectAtIndex:i]dimensions:CGSizeMake(30,30)
                                         alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter  fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30];     
        lblSelectedAlpha.position = ccp(fSelectedAlphaY,25);
        lblSelectedAlpha.tag=i;
        lblSelectedAlpha.color = ccc3(125,125,125);
        [tempBackground addChild:lblSelectedAlpha z:5];     
        fSelectedAlphaY +=25;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is how i implemented scrolling in my cocos2d game

// How to add scroll on label. This i did with a UITextView

// inside init, i took

{

```
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,430, 150, 50)]
    alphabetScroll = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,50 ,50)];
    alphabetScroll.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"verdana" size:30.0f];
    alphabetScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    alphabetScroll.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:125.0/255.0 green:125.0/255.0 blue:125.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
    alphabetScroll.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

    [scroll addSubview:alphabetScroll];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:scroll];
```

}

-(void)showSelectedAlphaBet

{

```
NSLog(@"showSelectedAlphaBet");

fSelectedAlphaY =26;   // I have 26 alphabets

if (tempBackground) {

    [tempBackground removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

// Area where alphabets are added on touch

```
tempBackground = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"stripe_2.png"];
tempBackground.position = ccp(160,30);
[self addChild:tempBackground z:30];
bottomAlphabet = @" ";

for (int i=0; i<[arryAddSelectedChar count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"[arryAddSelectedChar count] %@",[arryAddSelectedChar objectAtIndex:i]);

    bottomAlphabet = [bottomAlphabet stringByAppendingString:[arryAddSelectedChar objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

// Implementing shifting/scrolling

```
int newScrollViewWidth;
int newLabelWidth;
newScrollViewWidth =25*[arryAddSelectedChar count];
newLabelWidth =50*[arryAddSelectedChar count];

[scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(newScrollViewWidth, 45)];

alphabetScroll.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, newLabelWidth, 45);

alphabetScroll.text = bottomAlphabet;
if (newScrollViewWidth > 150) {
    CGPoint svos;
    CGPoint pt;
    svos = scroll.contentOffset;
    CGRect rc = [alphabetScroll bounds];
    rc = [alphabetScroll convertRect:rc toView:scroll];
    pt = rc.origin;
    pt.y = 0;
    pt.x += 20*([arryAddSelectedChar count]-5);

    [scroll setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];       
}
```

}

// In dealloc

```
[alphabetScroll release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling is simply a constant change in position over time. Basically something like this:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
   label.position = CGPointMake(label.position.x - 1, label.position.y);
}
```

Comment: This will probably reduce characters. What i need is to scroll and view characters that are removed from view due to addition of more characters.

Comment: I don't understand. Either you have a label with a string "ABCDEF.." and so on or you have 26+ labels each with a single character "A", "B", "C" and so on. To scroll them, you adjust their positions.

Comment: I have a label with a string "ABCDEF.." and so on...I am about to find the solution to my question. Will post it on completion.